# In Tableau, how to change Date Levels (and format !) dynamically with a parameter?

Tags: date, parameters, format, axis, tableau-api

Here is the official Tableau tutorial "Changing Date Level Dynamically" that I followed : http://kb.tableau.com/articles/knowledgebase/changing-date-level-dynamically

It allows to create a parameter to choose to display your data between "Weekly", "Monthly", and "Quarterly".

However, the format of the data is always "exact date".
I would like to switch between, not only "weekly", "monthly" and "quarterly" but also the format of the column (x-axis) between "week number"(1,2....52), "month" (January, February...) and "quarter" (1,2,3,4).

I would really appreciate your help.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Trying to understand your question.  You want to change the x axis labels to month, week number, or quarter?

Comment: @CharlieHaley Yes, I want to change the x axis labels to month, week number, or quarter, based on my choice of the parameter. Currently the parameter changes the VALUE of the measure of the x axis, which is dates (that changes with the parameter from month, week number, quarter) but my problem is that the FORMAT doesn't change. For example, if I switch the parameter to week number, the format will stay as "exact date". To summarize: the parameter changes the value of the measure, not its format; I want it to do both. Thanks and hope this helps.

Comment: @Aymeric The question is a year old but were you able to solve your problem? I am facing the exact same issue at the moment and cannot figure out a way around it. Thanks!